# Asynchronous show a POST

Tags: javascript, django, fetch

I am working on a twitter-like social network site.

In one single html page, I have a form to send the "tweet" and also down the form I have displayed all the "tweets" made by all users.

```
{% if posts %}
  {% for post in posts %}
    "html that creates the tweet, content, creation date, number of likes, etc."
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

To handle the form submission, I want the "tweets" to be shown asynchronously, so I`m doing a fetch POST request with JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

  fetch("", {

    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      body: document.querySelector('#new_message').value
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken')
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
      document.querySelector('#new_message').value = ""

      let div = document.createElement('div')
      div.innerHTML = ("<p>" + result.creation_date + "</p>"
                      + "<a href='#'>" + result.username + "</a>" + ' said:' +
                      '<br><br>'
                      +"<div class='container'>"
                          + "<p>" + result.body + "</p>" +
                      "</div>");

      div.style.cssText = "box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px; ; background-color:#F5F5F5; border-radius:10px; padding: 10px; margin: 5px;";

      document.querySelector('#plis').append(div);

  });
```

This works fine, the tweets are saved and also showed in the page without having to reload the entire page. But the problem is that I am handling the HTML in both sides. First when the request is GET and then when the method is POST (with the fetch request).

And this is impossible for me to make them look the same. The "tweet" that pops up when I submit the form wont look the same to the tweet I request via GET. Any ideas?

GET METHOD:

```
if request.method == "GET":
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            posts = Posts.objects.all().order_by('-creation_date')
            return render(request, "network/index.html", {
                "posts":posts
            })
```

Comment: We have no idea how you generate them in a GET without a [mcve]

Comment: there it is @charlietfl

Comment: Not really...how is the structure in index.html different than in the current page you render with javascript? Something must be different for them to look different

Comment: Oh i understand. I say different. But I could make them look the same. I just think this is not the best practise and there should be another way of doing it. Because writing html in both sides cannot be the best solution

Comment: Well an ajax call can also receive html. So you could actually share code server side between the two endpoints

Comment: How might you go about doing that? I tried to do it once but it returns the whole html and can't select the part that I need

Comment: You could have a server side method that only returns the html needed and use that in both locations. In the main page it would only render part of the page in the ajax route it would return only the needed html

Comment: Ok i'll see if I can do this. Thank you